# Initialize class with asynchronous variable

Tags: dart

How can I initialize a class with asynchronous variables so that they are set before the class is used? I have my class currently just calling an `async` `init` function but I would have to call that separately to wait for it to finish:

```
class Storage {

  String imageDirectory;
  String jsonDirectory;
  SharedPreferences instance;
  String uuid;

  init() async {
    imageDirectory = '${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/image_cache/';
    jsonDirectory = '${(await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path}/json_cache/';
    instance = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    uuid = instance.getString("UUID");
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might hope that you could have async factory constructors, but they [aren't allowed](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/23115).

So one solution is a `static getInstance()`, for example:

```
class Storage {
  static Future<Storage> getInstance() async {
    String docsFolder = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    return new Storage(
        docsFolder + '/image_cache/',
        docsFolder + '/json_cache/',
        (await SharedPreferences.getInstance()).getString('UUID'));
  }

  String imageDirectory;
  String jsonDirectory;
  String uuid;

  Storage(this.imageDirectory, this.jsonDirectory, this.uuid);
}
```

You could pass parameters into `getInstance` and thus into the constructor, as required. Call the above with:

```
Storage s = await Storage.getInstance();
```

Comment: This should not work: you might get error for this line: Storage s = await Storage.getInstance(); saying it's not an async function